# How to group by in DB2 IBM and get the first item in each group?

Tags: group-by, db2

I have a table like this:

```
|sub_account|name|email|
|-----------|----|-----|
// same account and same name: email different
|a1         |n1  |e1   |
|a1         |n1  |e2   |
// same account, name and email
|a2         |n2  |e3   |
|a2         |n2  |e3   |
```

I would like a query to get a table like this:

```
|sub_account|name|email|
|-----------|----|-----|
// nothing to do here
|a1         |n1  |e1   |
|a1         |n1  |e2   |
// remove the one that is exactly the same, but leave at least one
|a2         |n2  |e3   |
```

I've tried:

```sql
select sub_account, name, first(email)
from table
group by sub_account, name
```

but as you know "first" doesn't exists in the DB2; what is the alternative to it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
select sub_account, name, email
from table
group by sub_account, name, email
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in DB2. In SQL server, you can use DISTINCT for your issue.. You may try.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT sub_acount, name, email 
from TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a subquery with the table values + a counter (pos) that gets increased for each row and gets reset to 1 each time a new sub-account+name is reached.
The final query filters out all results from the subquery other than those with pos 1 (i.e. first entries of the group):

```sql
select *
from (
    select sub_account, name, email, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY sub_account, name 
                            ORDER BY email DESC) AS pos
    from table
    )
where pos = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```sql
SELECT  sub_account, 
        name, 
        CASE WHEN split_index=0 THEN MyList ELSE SUBSTR(MyList,1,LOCATE('|',MyList)-1) END
FROM    (select sub_account, name, LISTAGG(email,'|') as MyList, LOCATE('|',LISTAGG(LB_ARTICLE_CAISSE,'|')) AS split_index
         from TABLE
         group by sub_account, name) AS TABLEA
```

This function will aggregate your mail and after split it and take the first one